# data used in angular template should be provided from a controller

Tags: angularjs

```
namespace MyApp.Component.CarInfo {
    angular.module(MY_APP).component('bmwCarInfo', {
        template: `
            <span>
                <strong>30-Day Evaluation Period</strong> 
                <br />Charges will be applied once evaluation period finishes!
            </span>
        `
    });
}
```

Inside separate html page I have

```
<div ng-controller="CarController as $ctrl" ng-cloak>
    <bmw-car-info></bmw-car-info>
</div>
```

My question is: 
how can I provide data for number of days inside above template from a controller
  **XX-Day Evaluation Period**

Comment: Do you want to pass the data in from `CarController` or just set it in your `bmwCarInfo` component?

Comment: @Sophie I want to bind data from a controller to bmwCarInfo component

Comment: it's in the name, you need **bind**ings, e.g. (in component) `bindings: { info: '=' }`, (in html) `<bmw-car-info info="$ctrl.data">`, (in template) `{{$ctrl.info}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the binding in the component and pass the data through to the component as below.  See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture) for documentation.

```
angular.module(MY_APP).component('bmwCarInfo', {
    bindings: {
        days: '<'
    },
    template: `
        <span>
            <strong>{{$ctrl.days}}-Day Evaluation Period</strong> 
            <br />Charges will be applied once evaluation period finishes!
        </span>
    `
});

<div ng-controller="CarController as $ctrl" ng-cloak>
    <bmw-car-info days="$ctrl.days" />
</div>
```